# Call javascript function onclick in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have the following code in one of my views:

```
<button type="button" onclick="analyze();">Analyze</button>
```

And, the **.js.coffee** file for the corresponding controller contains

```
analyze = ->

  $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/logs"
    success: (data) ->
      Analytics.doAnalysis data
      return;

  return;
```

But, when I click the button, I get an error in console saying **Uncaught ReferenceError: analyze is not defined**. I think my onclick is not correctly defined. What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I am new to web development

Since you're new, let me give you some ideas on how to improve your code:

---

[**Unobtrusive JS (UJS)**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)

[This tutorial explains it *very* well](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3--net-15243)

Rails convention is geared towards "unobtrusive" javascript functionality. This means you can assign `events` to elements on your page without having to reference those elements directly (**don't use inline `onclick` etc**)

This is best described in the same way as CSS - using `inline` CSS is ridiculously laborious & seen as bad practice (it's not `DRY`). A much better way is to have a central stylesheet, which you can then use to style elements on the page.

Unobtrusive Javascript works in the same way - keep everything in files you call at runtime:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(".element").on("click", function(){
    ...
});
```

The importance of this cannot be stated enough - having unobtrusive JS is one of the best programming patterns you can apply; it not only DRIES up your code, but also ensures future development can be kept [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) (a gold standard in development)

---

**Ajax**

Since you're using ajax, you may wish to use the [Rails UJS Ajax functionality](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), which basically means this:

```
<%= button_to "Analyze", analytics_api_path, id: "analyze", remote: true %>
```

The **`remote: true`** option of this calls the [Rails UJS driver's `ajax` functionality](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L92) - basically setting up an ajax call without you having to write any code. The caveats of this are that you need to handle your own `ajax:success` process, and you'll need to point the element to the correct `href`

I would do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
$("#analyze").on "ajax:success", (data, status, xhr) ->
    Analytics.doAnalysis data
```

Answer (score 11):

Change this:

```
analyze = ->
```

To this:

```
window.analyze = ->
```

Functions in coffeescript are not global by default.

Comment: Thanks very much :) I am new to web development and had one more. Is there any way to access the function without making it global? What is the best practice?

Comment: "best" practice is debatable, but you might read up on "unobtrusive" javascript. In a perfect world, instead of your HTML pointing to Javascript functions, your javascript injects itself into the HTML. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript