# JQuery not working in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app. It has this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="commentSlide()">Comments</button>
```

I want the button to change color on the click event, but Rails seems to be having trouble reading my JQuery. The first of the two functions below works. When I remove it, I get this error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: commentSlide is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):81)
```

Here are my two functions. JavaScript works, JQuery does not. Help?

```
 function commentSlide(){
   alert("hello"); 
  }

 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

   function commentSlide(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red'); 
   }
})
```

Here is the top section of my javascript file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: You might want to check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989512/call-javascript-function-onclick-in-rails.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Using event listeners instead of an onClick event solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call javascript function onclick in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989512/call-javascript-function-onclick-in-rails)